# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE from web admin ejabberd docker

Tags: docker, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I am running ejabberd version 21.04 from docker in windows 10
whenever I try to use web admin while pressing the button in docker desktop
the browser gives me an error saying localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I use chrome as the web browser
I followed this tutorial https://hub.docker.com/r/ejabberd/ecs they are starting ejabberd container on port 5222, but when I run web admin it says invalid http response, for port 5222 and when I run on port 8000 it says err empty response from server

to check log I used docker exec -it ejabberd tail -f logs/ejabberd.log

```
2021-04-27 10:43:15.196032+00:00 [debug] <0.43.0>@application_controller:info_started/2:1929 PROGRESS REPORT:
    application: runtime_tools
    started_at: ejabberd@73fe5729d7a6
2021-04-27 10:43:15.196319+00:00 [debug] <0.43.0>@application_controller:info_started/2:1929 PROGRESS REPORT:
    application: artificery
    started_at: ejabberd@73fe5729d7a6
2021-04-27 10:43:15.196575+00:00 [debug] <0.43.0>@application_controller:info_started/2:1929 PROGRESS REPORT:
    application: distillery
    started_at: ejabberd@73fe5729d7a6
2021-04-27 10:43:16.037858+00:00 [debug] <0.651.0>@ejabberd:check_apps/0:139 All applications are intact
```

what should I do ?
do I have to change config file
thank you

Comment: In theory the web admin should work correctly if you follow the steps in the tutorial and use the batch script. Does everything else work correctly? I'll try it again as soon as I get a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: everything works fine except the api and web admin, when using curl http://localhost:522 gives me error <?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream id='10090203127154689979' version='1.0' xml:lang='en' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' xmlns='jabber:client'><stream:error><not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'/><text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'>syntax error</text></stream:error></stream:stream>

Comment: I've tested it, and Web works, using the Firefox browser. Update your post mentioning what web browser do you use, and mention if there's any error messages in C:/ejabberd/logs/error.log or strange messages in ejabberd.log

Comment: i updated the post but now i am getting empty response from the server even though reinstalling the container

Comment: can you tell me the steps you took to achieve the web admin

Comment: I followed the steps described in the tutorial, and then clicked in the Web icon.

Comment: did you choose ejabberd/ecs from docker hub? and which tutorial

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://hub.docker.com/r/ejabberd/ecs but still getting the same err

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When clicking on the "Open in Browser" icon in Docker Desktop, it will open using the lowest port number, see https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/9537

So, if you expose 5222 for C2S and 5280 for web admin, Docker Desktop opens the url http://localhost:5222 Am I right? That obviously will cause a problem!!! And you should have noticed that the port opened in the webbrowser is wrong!!!

Instead of installing the image and creating the container manually and then complaining, I followed this cool tutorial that bypasses that problem by performing all the actions automatically, and it sets 5180 for webadmin (instead of 5280), so Web Admin works correctly:

https://www.process-one.net/blog/install-ejabberd-on-windows-10-using-docker-desktop/